# Adjusting menu bar on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make menu with dropdown like on picture, but i cant make hover on items to be big as on picture i guess it was border with padding but when i try to make it so big it just dont work , and i cant make same thing on sub menu. Can anyone help me with this , please ?

this is how it should look [menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q6uE.png) - [sub menu item hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7r7V.png)

my css :

```css
ul.sidebar {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 15px;
 background: #d29bff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #d29bff 0%, #8977ff 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #d29bff 0%,#8977ff 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #d29bff 0%,#8977ff 100%);
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*padding: 10px;*/
}

ul.sidebar li {
 padding: 15px;
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #9d00ff;
}

ul.sidebar li:last-child {
 border-bottom: none;
}

ul.sidebar li a:hover {
 border: 1px solid #9d00ff;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 5px;
}

ul.sidebar li a {
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
}

ul.sidebar ul {
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 list-style: none;
}

ul.sidebar li:hover > ul{
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
 left: 82.5%;
 top: -3%;
 background: #b5aaff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

ul.sidebar li ul li a:hover{
 background: url("../images/arrowTask2.png")left no-repeat;
 padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title>CSS Styling Exam Variant 1 - Task 1</title>
 <link href="css/task2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <aside>
   <ul class="sidebar">
    <li>
     <a href="#">Sidebar Item #1</a>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item #1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item #1.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item #1.3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item #1.4</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Sidebar Item #2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Sidebar Item #3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Sidebar Item #4</a>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item #4.1</a>
      </li>                            
      <li>                             
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item #4.2</a>
      </li>                            
      <li>                             
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item #4.3</a>
      </li>                            
      <li>                             
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item #4.4</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Sidebar Item #5</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Sidebar Item #6</a>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </aside>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `but i cant make hover on items to be big as on picture` what this means? How big you want it to be. I think its looking same as its in your picture.

Comment: it isnt like on image up , its just around letters , but it should be bigger like on menu picture up above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `box-sizing: border-box;` to your `ul.sidebar li` [box-sizing](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/). Removed the padding from the unordered lists and centered the text on the `<li>`. `ul.sidebar li:hover > ul` this part changed due to the previous setup rules. I think you just needed to remove paddings and setup the specific position on your sub-menu to achieve what you want. Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5sjs607y/9/) Hope this helps.

```css
ul.sidebar {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 15px;
 background: #d29bff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #d29bff 0%, #8977ff 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #d29bff 0%,#8977ff 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #d29bff 0%,#8977ff 100%);
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.sidebar li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 15px;
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #9d00ff;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.sidebar li:last-child {
 border-bottom: none;
}

ul.sidebar li a:hover {
 border: 1px solid #9d00ff;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 5px;
}

ul.sidebar li a {
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
}

ul.sidebar ul {
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.sidebar li:hover > ul{
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
 left: 100%;
 top: -1%;
 background: #b5aaff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

ul.sidebar li ul li a:hover{
 background: url("../images/arrowTask2.png")left no-repeat; 
 padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <aside>
   <ul class="sidebar">
    <li>
     <a href="#">Sidebar Item #1</a>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item #1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item #1.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item #1.3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item #1.4</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Sidebar Item #2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Sidebar Item #3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Sidebar Item #4</a>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item #4.1</a>
      </li>                            
      <li>                             
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item #4.2</a>
      </li>                            
      <li>                             
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item #4.3</a>
      </li>                            
      <li>                             
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item #4.4</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Sidebar Item #5</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Sidebar Item #6</a>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Sub sidebar Item</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </aside>
 </div>
```